# Validating Java 8 dates

Tags: java, java-8

I'd like to validate several date formats, as below examples :

```
YYYY
YYYY-MM
YYYY-MM-DD
```

Validation must ensure that date format is correct and the date exists.

I'm aware that Java 8 provides a new Date API, so I'm wondering if it's able to do such job.

Is there a better way using Java 8 date API ?
Is it still a good practice to use Calendar class with lenient parameter ?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Comment: What do you expect as a date for "YYYY" ? "YYYY-01-01" ? Same question for "YYYY-MM".

Comment: It has never been a good practice to use `Calendar` class. `DateFormat` was always the one to use.

Comment: You should use the new [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) utilities introduced in [JSR-310](http://www.threeten.org/).  You should avoid the pre-Java-8 date utilities like `Calendar`.

Comment: If YYYY, validate that this year "exists" (Ok... we can consider that every YYYY year exists...)

Comment: Maybe a set of regex is better for this problem?

Comment: Regex is good if you want to test form, but it will most probably fail if you will want to test detailed content like `2222-33-44` or `2000-02-30`.

Comment: I could easily use date parse if i'd have just YYYY-MM-DD format. with YYYY and YYYY-MM format possibilities it's easier with regex

Answer (score 6):

You can specify missing fields with `parseDefaulting` to make all the formatters working:

```
public static boolean isValid(String input) {
    DateTimeFormatter[] formatters = {
            new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy")
                    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
                    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
                    .toFormatter(),
            new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy-MM")
                    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
                    .toFormatter(),
            new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
                    .parseStrict().toFormatter() };
    for(DateTimeFormatter formatter : formatters) {
        try {
            LocalDate.parse(input, formatter);
            return true;
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## Use optional fields and [`parseBest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseBest-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery...-)

You only want to validate, I understand that, but afterwards you'll most likely want to extract the data in an appopriate way. Fortunately, and indeed as you wrote, Java 8 provides such a method, `parseBest`.

`parseBest` works with optional fields. So define the format you want to parse first: `yyyy[-MM[-dd]]`, with the brackets (`[` and `]`) wrapping the optional fields.

`parseBest` also requires you to provide several `TemporalQuery<R>`. Actually, it's just a functional wrapper around a template method `<R> R queryFrom(TemporalAccessor)`. So we can actually define a `TemporalQuery<R>` as simply as `Year::from`. Good: that's exactly what we want. The thing is that `parseBest` is not really well named: it will parse all in order and stop after the first proper `TemporalQuery` that matches. So in your case, we have to go from most precise to less precise. Here are the various types that you want to handle: `LocalDate`, `YearMonth` and `Year`. So let's just define the `TemporalQuery[]` as `LocalDate::from, YearMonth::from, Year::from`. Now, if `parseBest` doesn't recognize your input, it will throw an exception.

All in all, we'll construct the `parseBest` as follow:

```
parseBest(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy[-MM[-dd]]"), LocalDate::from, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
```

So let's write it properly:

```
static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy[-MM[-dd]]");

static TemporalAccessor parseDate(String dateAsString) {
  return FORMATTER.parseBest(dateAsString, LocalDate::from, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
}
```

But... you only want to validate... Well in that case, a date is computed and the expensive job is already done. So let's just define the validation as follow:

```
public static boolean isValidDate(String dateAsString) {
  try {
    parseDate(dateAsString);
    return true;
  } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I know, it's bad to use exceptions to handle cases like this, but while the current API is very powerful this very specific case wasn't taken in account so let's just stick to it and use it as is.

But now, we have this issue: invalid dates can be parsed. For instance `"2018-15"` will be parsed as `Year{2018}` because `Year` is the best `TemporalAccessor` that the parser can use: `YearMonth` would fail, but it is a `YearMonth`, so it must be valid according to that. So let's just pass it again in the `FORMATTER`.

```
public static boolean isValidDate(String dateAsString) {
  try {
    TemporalAccessor date = parseDate(dateAsString);
    return FORMATTER.format(date).equals(dateAsString);
  } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here's the full code:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;
class Main {

  private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy[-MM[-dd]]");

  static TemporalAccessor parseDate(String dateAsString) {
    return FORMATTER.parseBest(dateAsString, LocalDate::from, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
  }

  public static boolean isValidDate(String dateAsString) {
    try {
      TemporalAccessor parsedDate = parseDate(dateAsString);
      return FORMATTER.format(parsedDate).equals(dateAsString);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {   &#32;
    String[] datesAsString = {
      "2018",
      "2018-05",
      "2018-05-22",
      "abc",
      "2018-",
      "2018-15",
    };
    for (String dateAsString: datesAsString) {
      System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", dateAsString, isValidDate(dateAsString) ? "valid" : "invalid");
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVNNa@MwEL3nVwyCgF1i0wYKxaEsWbY91bS0oVBCDhNZbpXaUiopoWHJb8@ObaV2mpT1wYxm9N68@dAC1xgtsvfdTpZLbRwsyBE7WYr4bNQ78uXalOhOhpyoPFhUQV6gtZCiVPC31wNYGrlGJ8A6dJJDLhUW8Ic8E0Le1pxOGLi9f0zHk8nNI1wfR2OdP9SGCtiGvmmUptMoy2YzFo4oBwD9fIKJ1zLmXFirDSzRWFFRBk/OSPUKGdlj2xxCElnhjXAro1oVcY36LawLutcHcKc5FhVbkuRGlwN4EWhSrdxb19HYtbZt3YTVvCBtXuJc60KgAmmfsZDZ/7Q5s/EW/FBdTUGNa0s94Bl58FGRzUiDliOMxccKC3sKvwWOjr9BsB/PQwW7@eRi6aRWIMIvlT5RTkzCg093Yq1lBiXtiq9/OgM0r5aY/FABvgKVJLvXRMXuk7Hh@cUVG3RP0fnlkSMaDlsfzvm3C9@OF3uCbaOfOgWnZpQcympb8LSx9CpivXIxvQDl8oD1bQJ921dsAIc71d2DwwX4BWxdhRgkwKRq7LDb0u1u9w8)

Output:

```
2018: valid
2018-05: valid
2018-05-22: valid
abc: invalid
2018-: invalid
2018-15: invalid
```

### You want more than validating, like getting the actual value?

Note that you can still use the data retrieved from `parseBest` for further uses like this:

```
TemporalAccessor dateAccessor = parseDate(dateAsString);
if (dateAccessor instanceof Year) {
  Year year = (Year)dateAccessor;
  // Use year
} else if (dateAccessor instanceof YearMonth) {
  YearMonth yearMonth = (YearMonth)dateAccessor;
  // Use yearMonth
} else if (dateAccessor instanceof LocalDate) {
  LocalDate localDate = (LocalDate)dateAccessor;
  // Use localDate
}
```

But be careful because as mentioned earlier, `"2018-15"` will still be parsed, as `Year{2018}` and not `YearMonth{2018,15}`, or `"2018-02-30"` will still be parsed as a `YearMonth` and not as a `LocalDate`.

Comment: How can we validate two formats "yyyy-MM-dd[\'T\'HH:mm:SSX]" using the parseBest? When trying to validate it it's only converting it into LocalDate and chopping the time part.

Comment: @Vishwaksena I believe that your question deserves an entire question by itself, instead of a mere comment. Make sure to specify that you want to use `parseBest`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137376/is-there-a-way-to-parse-two-different-datetime-formats-into-localdatetime-or-ins

Comment: this will fail if month is invalid "2018-15"

Comment: @PanditBiradar How is that a problem? The "2018-15" is invalid, it must fail!

Comment: @Olivier Grégoire the above programs give o/p for "2018-15" is valid instead of invalid ``2018-15: valid``

Comment: @PanditBiradar You are right. I fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

To validate the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, you can simply use [`LocalDate.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) introduced in `java.time` since JDK 8.

> Obtains an instance of LocalDate from a text string such as
>   2007-12-03.
>
> The string must represent a valid date and is parsed using
>   DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.

A [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) will be thrown if the date is invalid.

For the other two formats you gave us, the exception would be thrown. That is logical because they are not real date, simply part of a date.

---

LocalDate also provide a method `of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)` thus if you really want to validate simply the year in some case, the year with the month in other case or the full date then you could do something like this :

```
public static final boolean validateInputDate(final String isoDate)
{
    String[] dateProperties = isoDate.split("-");

    if(dateProperties != null)
    {
        int year = Integer.parseInt(dateProperties[0]);

        // A valid month by default in the case it is not provided.
        int month = dateProperties.length > 1 ? Integer.parseInt(dateProperties[1]) : 1;

        // A valid day by default in the case it is not provided.
        int day = dateProperties.length > 2 ? Integer.parseInt(dateProperties[2]) : 1;

        try
        {
            LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
            return true;
        }
        catch(DateTimeException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Note that you mentionned *several formats* but did not provide them, so I assumed these were the only 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final boolean validateInputDate(final String isoDate, final String dateFormat){
    final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    try {
        final Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(isoDate);
        System.out.println("Date: " + date);
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lenient, is your default is true:

in SimpleDAteFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFromat);
sdf.setLenient(false);
```

or in JSON validate:

```
@JsonFormat(lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code. This will validate and also works in every format.

```
public class DateValidator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String datetoCheck = "999999";

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMdd");
        try {
            LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(datetoCheck, formatter);
            System.out.println(localDate);
        } catch ( DateTimeException ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```