# Is there a way to parse two different dateTime formats into LocalDateTime or Instant in java?

Tags: date, java-8, datetime-format

How can we validate two formats "yyyy-MM-dd" and "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSX" for a given string which can be of any of the two formats and either convert it to Instant or LocalDateTime?

```
LocalDateTime dateTime;
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd[\'T\'HH:mm:SSX]");
    TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = formatter.parseBest(now, LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from);
    if (temporalAccessor instanceof LocalDateTime) {
      dateTime = (LocalDateTime)temporalAccessor;
    } else {
      dateTime = ((LocalDate)temporalAccessor).atStartOfDay();
    }
```

When using the above format it's always resolving to LocalDate and chopping the time part.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the format to "yyyy-MM-dd[\'T\'HH:mm:ssX]" fixed it.